# Getting total operators from Java file

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree

I am using the ASTParser in Java and am trying to find the number of operators in a sample java file.

for example in this sample file

```
public class ArithmeticOperatorsExample {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

                System.out.println("Arithmetic operators example :");

                int i = 50 + 20;
                int j = i - 10;
                int k = j * 2;
                double l = k / 6;



        }
}
```

I should get an answer of 4. How would I use the ASTParser to get the total number of operators?

This is what  I have so far, this just tracks the variables

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AST;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTVisitor;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ChildListPropertyDescriptor;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ChildPropertyDescriptor;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.SimpleName;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.SimplePropertyDescriptor;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.VariableDeclarationFragment;

public class Main {

    static StringBuffer buffer;
    static ASTParser parser;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        readFile();

        runAstParser();



}

    private static void runAstParser() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        parser=ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
        parser.setSource(buffer.toString().toCharArray());
        parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);

        final CompilationUnit cu=(CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
        ASTVisitor c;


        cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
            Set names= new HashSet();

            public boolean visit(VariableDeclarationFragment node){
                SimpleName name=node.getName();


                this.names .add(name.getIdentifier());
                System.out.println("Declaration of '" + name + "' at line "
                        + cu.getLineNumber(name.getStartPosition()));

                return false;
            }
        });



    }

    private static void readFile() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File javaFile=new File("C:/Users/Jacob_2/Eclipse/java-neon/eclipse/sampleJava.java");
        try {
            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(javaFile));
            buffer=new StringBuffer();
            String line=null;

            while(null!=(line=reader.readLine())){
                buffer.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }





    }
}
```

anyone have any ideas on how to use ASTParser to get operators in a java file?

Comment: Actually, you should get 8 because `=` is also an operator. What have you tried to code so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I uploaded what i have so far